# How to make mmenu trigger newly added items (selected functionality)

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I'm using http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/ and it works great.

However, when adding items dynamically to a menu, the selected class does not work for these dynamic added items.

The code looks something like this:

HTML

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul id="ulmenu">
       <li class="Selected"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#ulmenu").append('<li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>');
```

Is there a way to trigger a refresh, or anohter way to dynamically add elements that can use this selected class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the **selected** class is added to the **li's** when you **tap/click** on it. Its part of the functionality of the plugin.

So what you can do is when you append the new item say-

```
$("#ulmenu").append('<li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>');
```

You should add the tap event on which it will add the selected class to this item. something like this:

```
 $("#ulmenu").append('<li class="dynamic"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>');
    $('.dynamic').on('tap',function(){

    $(this).addClass('Selected');

    });
```

Comment: The problem is not having the selected class by itself, but it doesn't work like this. The problem is when you click on such a new item, it doesn't get highlighted like the others. This functionality is coded into mmenu itself.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uU4mk/2/)**

Please use event delegation for dynamically added HTML elements

```
 $("#ulmenu").append('<li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>');

    $("#ulmenu").on("click","li a",exe);

    $("#ulmenu").find("li a:last").trigger("click");

    function exe(){
    alert(1);  // here do your work
    }
```

Comment: I could to it manually like this, but it has the functionality built in, and I prefer to use the existing functionality